# Python script crashes after opening selenium Chrome web driver in a specific profile

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using python to open chrome web driver in a specific profile as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r'user-data-dir=C:\Users\retro\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 1')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'chromedriver.exe', options=options)
```

The script trying to run it shows the following error stack. However the window is opened in Chrome in the profile I wanted and it stays open in there!

Full Error Stack:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 10.0.20180 x86_64)
```

### EDIT 1:

I have added following two options as well which some solutions suggested but still no use:

```
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
```

And I have made sure that I'm using right webdriver version i.e. 84 which matches my chrome version. When I try with latest version it throws an error that the driver version is only usable with chrome version 85.

### EDIT 2:

I have added port number as well:

```
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
```

Adding which although result in same outcome, it changes error stack as follows:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 10.0.20180 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 10.0.20180 x86_64)
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.42*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.42*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v68-70**

- Possibly you are using the latest *chrome=84.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v84.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/84.0.4147.30/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 84**

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v2.42* and the *Chrome Browser v84.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v84.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=84.0.4147.30/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 84.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v84.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/84.0.4147.30/notes.txt))
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.